# How to change following sentence into Reported Speech?

Tags: indirect-speech

This is not the time or place for this. Please, help I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: They said it was not the time or place for this.

Comment: He said that this was neither . . .nor would work well here.

Answer (score 1):

**"They claimed it was neither the time nor the place for that, and asked for help."**

If the subject is known, you want to use the personal pronoun (he/she) accordingly.

Comment: Good! I do wonder, however, if OP meant you to report his plea for help, or just respond to it. :)

Comment: @Conrado    The OP means "reported speech", and that's it.

Comment: True, but it says: "the following _sentence_"-a single object. I thought you were being facetious.